# how to ensure local decimal separator in iOS

Tags: ios, localization, nsnumberformatter

I've trouble understanding the number formatter in iOS. I set the locale in the iPhone Simulator but the decimal separator on the screen is always "." but should be ",". I don't want to set the decimal separator to fix it. It should adjust by the system based on the locale settings. All answers I found so far were not really answering my issue. In osx there is the option to localize all number outputs.
Is there additional special code required in iOS?

Comment: Show the code you are using to format the number.

Comment: Hello Maddy, I'm a beginner and this is just a question in general. I found a solution in the meantime using `localizedStringWithFormat`. Thanks for your "help" anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my issue myself. I need to specifically define the localization for outputs of NSNumbers in labels or text fields. It is not done by the system automatically.
Using a ´NSNumberFormatter` for localization the output could look like this:

```
formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
cell.yourLabel.text = [NSString StringWithFormat:@"%@", [formatter stringForObjectValue:yourString]];
```

Another option would be using the ´localizedStringWithFormat´ method:

```
NSNumber *yourNumber = [nf numberFromString:yourString];
//to create the formatted NSNumber object
NSString *yourString = [NSString localizedStringWithFormat:@"%.2F", yourNumber];
```